# Cutting a part of path

Tags: c#, path

I have two paths: 'C:\ol\il\ek' and 'ek\mek\gr'. How can i cut the common part from these paths? I'm making one paths from them like that (h- first path, n - second path):

```
                 ee.Load(h + "\\" + n);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the "common part" is always the last segment of the first path, and the first segment of the second one, you can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to strip this segment from the first path and combine the result with the second path using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

```
var result = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\ol\il\ek"), @"ek\mek\gr");

//  result == @"C:\ol\il\ek\mek\gr"
```

Comment: Sorry - I missed your qualifier about "Common part"  ;)  I was assuming, from the OP, that there could be more than one common path...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following class, that I think could meet your needs. First I split paths in single directory parts. Than I check last parts of path1 with first of path2, increasing num of parts I compare, until I reach parts limit or get equal parts.
When I found equal parts in the two paths, I clear path2 parts.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JoinPaths(@"C:\ol\il\ek", @"ek\mek\gr"));
        Console.WriteLine(JoinPaths(@"C:\ol\il\ek", @"il\ek\mek\gr"));
        Console.WriteLine(JoinPaths(@"C:\ol\il\ek", @"ol\il\ek\mek\gr"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] source, int start, int end)
    {
        if (end < 0)
            end = source.Length + end;
        var len = end - start;
        var res = new T[len];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            res[i] = source[i + start];
        return res;
    }

    private static string JoinPaths(string path1, string path2)
    {
        var parts1 = path1.ToLower().Split(new char[] { '\\' });
        var parts2 = path2.ToLower().Split(new char[] { '\\' });

        int commonPartLen = 1;
        while (commonPartLen<parts1.Length && commonPartLen<parts2.Length)
        {
            string slice1 = string.Join("\\", parts1.Slice(parts1.Length - commonPartLen, parts1.Length ));
            string slice2 = string.Join("\\", parts2.Slice(0, commonPartLen));

            if (slice1 == slice2)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < commonPartLen; i++)
                    parts2[i] = "";
                break;
            }
            commonPartLen++;
        }


        string firstPath = string.Join("\\", parts1.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)));
        string secondPath = string.Join("\\", parts2.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)));
        return firstPath + "\\"+secondPath; ;
    }
}
```

I hope the code is clear.